# Using Factory Design Pattern in Spring

Tags: java, design-patterns, spring

I organized the factory design pattern but I'm not sure if I used it right or wrong.

Here's my data model;

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
abstract public class Ga implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1977929156280284414L;

    private String id;
    private GaStaEnum gaStaEnum;
    private PlaTuEnum plaTuEnum;
    private BoaSiEnum boaSiEnum;

}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class XGa extends Ga {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3116827666531342601L;

    private Pla pla1;
    private Pla pla2;
    private int index;

.....
```

And my factory pattern is like this;

```
public class GaFactory {

    public static Ga createGa(GaType type) {
        Ga ga = null;

        if (X.equals(type)) {
            ga = new XGa();
        }

        return ga;
    }

}
```

I called the factory like this;

```
public XGaDTO init() {
    Ga xGa = GaFactory.createGa(X);
    repository.save((XGa) xGa);
    return mapper.toDTO((XGa) xGa);
}
```

Did I use it right? Or maybe I should add something more?

Thanks for advices.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please explain what your code accomplishes, both in the title and the question; it may be difficult to understand what exactly it's doing for someone who (like me) has no idea what "Pla", "BoaSi" or "Ga" mean, which in turn makes it harder to review your code and help you.

Comment: Hi @cliesens . I couldn't share all of my variables because of the credential of code but all I want is to get review for my factory design pattern usage and it is okay to not know the variables at this point, I guess.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** If you can't fully delegate the subclass decision to the factory and then live with whatever class it chose, then either re-factor the code to make that possible, or forget about the factory. And have the factory produce usable instances, not empty ones.

I see two (related) flaws in your code. (Disclaimer: maybe the code you showed us is a stripped-down version of the real application, then maybe some of my remarks don't apply.)

### Uninitialized instances

Your `createGa()` method in the `GaFactory` class creates a non-initialized `Ga` instance, one where all fields are left blank.

In my understanding, a factory is meant to create usable instances, and I guess that fields like `id` have to be filled before a `Ga` instance gets meaningful.

[If you order a car from a real-world factory, and you get one without engine or paint, you'd sue the factory.]

### Polymorphism flaw

My understanding of the factory pattern is that the factory creates an instance that fulfills the caller's needs.

In your case, I don't see how this could ever work the way it is intended. In `init()`, you have to cast the `Ga` instance coming from the factory to an `XGa`. If the `repository.save()` and `mapper.toDTO()` really need the cast, then using the factory instead of directly calling `new XGa()` leads to more obscure code, and to code where errors will be found not at compile-time, but at run-time.

No compiler will know that `GaFactory.createGa(X)` creates an `XGa`, and not eg. a `MyGa`, so a small typo can easily create a `ClassCastException` at runtime, hopefully detected by an automated test, and not in production.

If you use a factory the way you do, make sure that only code "inside the factory" has to know about the existence of subclasses like `XGa` or `MyGa`. Everything outside the factory should accept any `Ga` subclass. This not only applies to places like `repository.save()` and `mapper.toDTO()`, but also to the initialization phase. I guess that in your code, the only way to initialize `pla1`, `pla2`, and `index`, is to use a setter in the `XGa` subclass, again needing a cast.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What I understand from your answer is that I used polymorphism wrong as casting would be needed. At this point I'm stuck because I need **XGa** outside of the factory. Could you please show me a little example how to do it?

Comment: My plain old Java advice then is to not use a factory, but directly create `XGa` instances where you need them by calling `new XGa()`. If you can't fully hide the subclass system behind the factory, don't use a factory. But I'd try to improve the `repository.save()` and `mapper.toDTO()` (and similar) methods, in a way that they accept any `Ga` instance and do the dispatching themselves, ideally by delegating to methods overridden in the various `Ga` subclasses.